# Python: Basic maths for linear algebra

Tags: python-2.7, linear-algebra

I have written a program that should be able to solve a system of linear equations in the style of ax + bx ... = n using the Gaussian elimination.

At the core of my program there are these simple lines:

```
        e = ((-1)*d*b + a*e)
        f = ((-1)*d*c + a*f)
```

d, e and f are all coefficients of x1, x2 and x3 respectively.
When trying a trivial question and asking the computer to calculate e and f and q when all values are equal to 1, this is the result:

```
e=1.0, f=1.0
```

Instead of all values being 0, as it should be.

```
e = ((-1)*1*1 + 1*1) => 0!
```

All numbers are float-types.

My printing command looks like the following

```
            row1 = ("" + repr(b) + "x + " + repr(c) + "")
            print row1
```

and the output

```
1.0x + 1.0x
```

Have I overlooked some simple problem?

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm? `(-1)*d*a + a*d` will be always 0 because `a*d=d*a`

Comment: Exactly this is the point behind my algorithm. I am eliminating the first variable and have to change the other ones respectively. But as a=d=c=e, a*e=d*c and so on. Therefore, all values should be 0.

Comment: In that case, why not write `d=0` and eliminate d from the rest of the code? Less confusing

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that... The point is, why are the other values not equal to 0? Basic maths tells me they should

Comment: You set `e = a*e`. What are the values of a and e at that point?

Comment: All values are equal to 1. That's why it is so weird that I get one as a result (see the post, I edited it a few times to make it more clear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake.

I used a recursive formula for `d`, and therefore the value changed where it shouldn't have had.

Thanks @Joni for your help :)